# Is it possible to make a web link to open a local AppData folder?

Tags: windows, url

For support purposes for an online virtual world viewer [Second Life, Firestorm], we often need users to clear a specific folder from Roaming & Local.

Many of our users have great difficulty locating these folders, as they are hidden by default, & the instructions to reveal them are fairly confusing to a beginner.

To be able to give them a 'URL' link to click that would open their own %appdata% & %localappdata% would be a boon.

Comment: Try `file://%appdata%`

Comment: That simple? I'll give it a go - report back...

Comment: oh, I so wish it was that simple... Safari says, 'You need IE to do that' IE just totally ignores it. Thanks for the suggestion, though.

Comment: `Start | Run | %appdata%`

Comment: TY Steve - but you're over-estimating our user-base ;-)

Comment: So you want let users with this knowledge delete files? lol

Comment: Yes - the essential quest is to give users fast access to these 'hidden folders' & allow them to trash specific folders in there. It's all caveat emptor, they have to find & delete the correct folder, just a hint as to where it is would help them.

Answer (score 3):

Even though I suggested `file://%appdata%`, I didn't actually think it would work -- at least not cross-browser and across the Internet. ;)

`file://` was deprecated greatly many years ago, due to the security implications of allowing a remote site ANY access to your file system.  I think with IE, file:// still works, but only if it's from an local, or perhaps a trusted Intranet page.

- The best way to deal with this is to fix whatever is wrong that causing people to have to remove that directory.
- The next best way would be to just provide a set of instructions and get them to follow them.
- After that, I'd suggest writing a program/script that finds and deletes the folder(s) in question and make it available to the users to download.

Comment: responses, in order of posting rather than misery factor... ;-)
1) I so wish, but cannot be done, mainly for political reasons. versioning & recallable prefs are not guaranteed, even with sanity checks. 2) There is already a comprehensive structure, unfortunately many people are not capable of following it. 3) Would generate too many 'sky is falling/malware' panics. I really do appreciate your input though, thank you.

Comment: @Tetsujin You can create and host Bat file on site what will clear this folder. I am sure about 99.9% antivirus will found nothing malicious.

Comment: The quest is "fewest click by least competent users, with no proviso for 'scary malware' "

Comment: @Tetsujin  1) Political reason are bunk; make a case that their lack of will to fix it is causing users to have problem.  Users with problems = ex-customers (eventually).  2) If you provide simple step-by-step instructions, with pictures, and they can't follow it, then it's not your fault and shouldn't be your problem.  3) If they trust you as a vendor, then they should trust the program/script your providing. They can always run it through Virustotal.com if they're afraid. :)

Comment: In the end I still firmly believe you're not going to be able to do this in the way you want, especially if the users are as mentally handicapped as you make them out to be. If they really can't follow simple instructions like "Hit Start, in the Search box type %Appdata%, hit enter", then I have to wonder how they turn on their computer, or open their browsers, since that's easily as many steps. ;)

Comment: Tongue-in-cheek answers to your points... 1) the politics is they're not customers, we're not paid, it's all voluntary. 2) Correct, yet they still come back to cry that it no werky. 3) actually might be a possibility to look into... & ... 4) I do wonder myself if some have to ask nurse where the on-switch is every morning ;-)